# php playing tricks when I send an "8" as an argument

Tags: php, function, file

I can't understand what the hack is going on with my code))) May be I just need more experience but... Let's get down to business:

I wrote a function which returns an array with some statistic data for my system, all I need is just to specify the arguments as Year, M, D. If I send something like `getStatData(2016,07,07)` - works fine, But just as i send something with a digit eight - it fails! eg.: `getStatData(2016,07,08)` Of course I have a file the fn requires, more over It works fine if a specify args as strings ('2016', '07', '08'); But this is ain't cool:D

**The function:**

```
function getStatData($y,$m,$d=false){
if(isset($y) && is_numeric($y) && isset($m) && is_numeric($m)){

    $m=($m<10)? '0'.$m : $m;

    if(isset($d)){
        $d=($d<10)? '0'.$d : $d;
        $y= 'days/'.$y;         
        $data = file_get_contents(STATDIR.'/'.$y.'/'.$m.'_'.$d.'.json');
    }

    else {      
        $data = file_get_contents(STATDIR.'/'.$y.'_'.$m.'.json');
    }
    return json_decode($data, true);
}
    else return false;
}
```

Calling...

```
    print_r(getStatData(2016,07,08)); //call with 08
```

**ERROR:** file_get_contents(core/statistic/days/2016/07_00.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: With string arguments `getStatData('2016','07','08')` you will have `2016/007_008.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass arguments as string like print_r(getStatData('2016','07','08'));

As a side note use str_pad() function to format month and date to 2 digit value. Instead if isset($d) use if($d)

```
function getStatData($y,$m,$d=false){
    if(isset($y) && is_numeric($y) && isset($m) && is_numeric($m)){
        // use str_pad
        $m=str_pad($m, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

        if($d){
            // use str_pad
            $d=str_pad($d, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $y= 'days/'.$y;
            $data = file_get_contents(STATDIR.'/'.$y.'/'.$m.'_'.$d.'.json');
        }

        else {
            $data = file_get_contents(STATDIR.'/'.$y.'_'.$m.'.json');
        }
        return json_decode($data, true);
    }
    else return false;
}

print_r(getStatData('2016','07','08'));
```

Comment: You can directly use $m= str_pad($m, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) and $d= str_pad($d, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).

Answer (score 2):

Numbers with a zero prefix are [octal literals](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php), rather than zero padded decimal integers. It seems that invalid octals are silently treated as `0` in [PHP 5](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70193). You should pass in `7` and `8` in the example you have provided.

In PHP 7 you will get a parse error. E.g. `Parse error: Invalid numeric literal in php shell code on line 1`.

Comment: `07` octal is `7` decimal. `08` is not valid.

Comment: Ah yes. Penny drops